# Chartjs - Fill dates between given labels

Tags: chart.js

I've been experimenting with Chartjs for several hours now and I'm not sure if this is possible. I have some data that is sorted date wise but not all dates are included. For example:

```
const salesChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('graph-sales'),
    {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['Aug 23','Aug 26','Aug 31','Sep 02'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Sales',
                borderColor: '#ccc',
                data: [2750.00,1100.00,3080.00,4320.00],
            }]
        }
    }
);
```

Chartjs plots this data as 4 datapoints and joins them with a line like so
[image: chartjs screenshot]

This is fine, but I want intermediate days to be added on the chart with datapoint value being 0. So essentially it would be like passing this data:

```
labels: ['Aug 23','Aug 24','Aug 25','Aug 26','Aug 27','Aug 28','Aug 29','Aug 30','Aug 31','Sep 01','Sep 02'],
datasets: [{
    label: 'Sales',
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    data: [2750.00,0,0,1100.00,0,0,0,0,3080.00,0,4320.00],
}]
```

I've looked into timescales but can't get them to work. The docs says I need a time adapter but there's no example of it in use so I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: If you are using ajax, you could fill in the date and  pass the data from controller to get each date data.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to do this on the backend serving up the data; but this code works if you want to do it in JavaScript on the frontend.

My method was to use a defined self-executing function which returns an array containing two arrays.

The first array is called **finalLabels** and contains all date strings between, and including, the dates provided in the original labels.

Which gives us `['Aug 23', 'Aug 24', 'Aug 25', 'Aug 26', 'Aug 27', 'Aug 28', 'Aug 29', 'Aug 30', 'Aug 31', 'Sep 01', 'Sep 02']`

The second returned array is called **finalDatas** and contains all of the original data values at the same index of the original label; and a value of zero where the value wasn't previously defined.

Which gives us: `[2750, 0, 0, 1100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3080, 0, 4320]`

**Working Codepen:** https://codepen.io/vpolston/pen/NWMgwOw

My account doesn't have ability to embed pictures, but this is what you end up with: [image of final chart created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDZSN.png).

JS

```
const labels = ['Aug 23','Aug 26','Aug 31','Sep 02'];
const data = [2750.00,1100.00,3080.00,4320.00];

const datasets = (function () {
  
  const months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul","Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
  
  /* define start and end date from labels and create date objects */
  const startDateString = labels[0];
  const endDateString = labels[labels.length - 1];
  const startDateObj = new Date(startDateString);
  const endDateObj = new Date(endDateString);
  
  /* create empty dates array to hold dates within range */
  let dates = [];
  
  /* 
  create currentDateObj var to increment in while loop 
  loop through, add currentDateObj to array, increment until false
  */
  let currentDateObj = new Date(startDateString);
  while( currentDateObj <= endDateObj ){
    
    /* format date to match the provided label and push to dates array */
    let dateString = currentDateObj.toDateString();
    let month = months[currentDateObj.getMonth()];
    let day = currentDateObj.getDate();
    
    if( day < 10 ){
      day = '0' + day
    };
    
    let date = month + ' ' + day; 
    dates.push(date);
    
    /* increment CurrentDateObj */
    currentDateObj.setDate(currentDateObj.getDate() + 1);
    
  };
  
  /* 
  use counter to loop through original datas
  */
  let valueExistsCounter = 0;
  
  let finalLabels = [];
  let finalDatas = [];
  
  for( const [index, date] of dates.entries() ){

    if( labels.includes(date) ){
      
      /* if date was provided in labels get the data value */
      finalLabels.push(date);
      finalDatas.push(data[valueExistsCounter]);
      
      valueExistsCounter += 1

    } else {
      
      /* set date value to 0 */
      finalLabels.push(date);
      finalDatas.push(0);
      
    }
    
  };
  
  return [finalLabels, finalDatas]

}());

const finalLabels = datasets[0];
const finalDatas = datasets[1];

/* now we can build the chart */
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: finalLabels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Sales',
      'fill': true,
      borderColor: '#ccc',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(204,204,204,0.5)',
      tension: 0.2,
      data: finalDatas
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          color: 'rgba(204,204,204,0.1)'
        }
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          color: 'rgba(204,204,204,0.1)'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<!-- Canvas -->
<div class="chartContainer">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<!-- include Chart.js 3.9.1  -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.js" integrity="sha512-d6nObkPJgV791iTGuBoVC9Aa2iecqzJRE0Jiqvk85BhLHAPhWqkuBiQb1xz2jvuHNqHLYoN3ymPfpiB1o+Zgpw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #0d1117;
}

.chartContainer {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

I think that covers it? If that was helpful please mark answered.

Comment: Yeah I realized its a lot of work to handle it on the frontend if the library doesn't support it. I'm handling it on the server as of now.